# Toggle multiple functions sequentially on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of independent functions - `fn1()`, `fn2()`, `fn3()`, `fn4()`.

I only need one function running at a time but the functions should toggle, on click of a single button, in a sequence `fn1()` [click] `fn2()` [click] `fn3()` [click] `fn4()` [click] back to `fn1()`

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Are you saying that on each successive click of an element a different function should be run?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan exactly

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function fn1(){}
function fn2(){}
function fn3(){}

var i = 1;

function myclick(){
   if (i == 1)
      fn1();
   elseif (i == 2)
      fn2();
   elseif (i == 3) {
      fn3();
      i = 1;
   }

   i++;
}
```

Everytime you call myclick, it runs one fn and then adds 1 to i. The next time it runs the 2nd fn, followed by the 3rd.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Jackson Ng

Comment: 4-th click would not be fn1() but fn2()

Comment: @natchkebiailia solved that. i value should be 0 in the last else call

Answer (score 5):

If I've understood what you're trying to do, you want to run a different function on successive clicks on a single element.

To do that you can put each function in an array, then run through each one using the modulo operator to return to the start of the array once the end is reached, something like this:

```js
var functions = [function() {
  console.log('first');
}, function() {
  console.log('second');
}, function() {
  console.log('third');
}, function() {
  console.log('fourth');
}];

$('button').click(function() {
  var i = ($(this).data('i') + 1) || 0;
  functions[i % functions.length]();
  $(this).data('i', i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a closure to keep track of which function you want to execute.

Html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="foo()"></button>
```

Js:

```
var foo = (function() {
    var funcIndex = 0;
    return function() {
        switch(funcIndex) {
            case 0: func1(); break;
            case 1: func2(); break;
            case 2: func3(); break;
            case 3: func4(); break;
        }

        funcIndex = (funcIndex+1) % 4;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr=[fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4];
var i=0;
$("buttonId").click(function(){
   arr[i%4]();
   i++;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="toogle()">Click Me</button>
```

Then

```
var index = 0;
var funcArr= [f1,f2,f3,f4];
function toogle(){
  funcArr[index]();
  index++;
  index = index%funcArr.length;
}

function f1(){console.log("f1")};
function f2(){console.log("f2")};
function f3(){console.log("f3")};
function f4(){console.log("f4")};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8chvusaq/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach :

```
function fn1()
{
    //do something
    $("#myButton").off("click");
    $("#myButton").click(fn2);
}

function fn2()
{
    //do something
    $("#myButton").off("click");
    $("#myButton").click(fn3);
}

function fn3()
{
    //do something
    $("#myButton").off("click");
    $("#myButton").click(fn4);
}

function fn4()
{
    //do something
    $("#myButton").off("click");
    $("#myButton").click(fn1);
}

$("#myButton").click(fn1);
```

Comment: Just FYI you're adding new event handlers on each successive click, and you never remove any. On the fourth click all four event handlers will run

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're right, I had that issue yesterday, I'll edit my post about it